# Can I do anything about serial or malicious downvoting?

Tags: support

I've heard of it happening to other people but now it's happening to me, a bunch of my old / unrelated questions and answers were downvoted in the space of a few minutes.

Do I report it and if so, how?

[image]

**UPDATE**

The very next day, the system works.

[image]

Comment: Related: [What does “Serial downvoting reversed” mean?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3564/21267)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a phenomenon called *serial downvoting*. It happens quite regularly, but there are automated scripts to catch it, and reverse it.

Quoting from [*What can I do if I’m the victim of serial down voting?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28758/226928) on Meta SE:

> There are three ways to fix it:
>
> 1. Do NOTHING. The daily vote anomaly script will pick it up and your rep
>      will be recalculated automatically.
> 2. If after 36 hours (give the script
>      time to run) you still see a problem, then flag one of your posts and
>      ask a moderator to look into the anomalous voting patterns.
> 3. If it
>      still hasn't been corrected, contact the SE team via the "contact us"
>      link at the bottom of any page on the site.

Comment: Very helpful answer, much appreciated.